# Python - removing copy paste code in subclasses

Tags: python, coding-style, refactoring

I have two classes `Z1` and `Z0` in my legacy code which are basically a copy paste. They both contain functions `f1() ... f6()` which are similar and function `f7()` in which they differ in string. `Class Z1` contains `string` "Z1" while `Z0` contains `string` "Z0" in `function f7()`.

The classes have the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
class Z1(Y1)
class Y1(D)
class D(B)


class Z2(Y2)
class Y2(B)


Z1 -> Y1 -> D -> B
Z2 -> Y2 ------> B
```

What is the best way to get rid off this copy paste code in Python?

Comment: I would rewrite everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you can safely add `f1() ... f6()` to B, then you could just do that, and use `type(self).__name__` instead of hard-coding `Z0` or `Z1`. That would probably be the easiest solution, but also the one that potentially introduces the most bloat.

If you don't want to bloat B, I would probably make a separate class (let's say `C`), add `f1()...f7()` (with the modified `f7`) to `C`, and have Z1 and Z2 inherit from both C and Y1/Y2 - but at that point you may want to think about restructuring the code in general.

Either way, you'll probably want to use introspection to get rid of the hard-coded class names because hard coding stuff isn't very elegant :)